# How can I pass arguments to the event handler when I trigger an event?

Tags: jquery, script#

In script#, I have the following:

```
jQuery.Select("#someId").Trigger("item-added", new object[]{"ball"} );
```

This compiles into the following Javascript:

```
$('#someId').trigger('item-added', [ 'ball' ]);
```

The above code works fine. The problem comes in declaring an event handler that can receive the argument array.

In order for my handler to receive the argument array, it would have to have a signature as such:

```
public void OnItemAdded(jQueryEvent jqe, Object[] args)
```

However, the only type available is:

```
public delegate void jQueryEventHandler(jQueryEvent e)
```

And as such, when the handler is called, the args are nowhere to be found.

I've read about the other methods of passing arguments to event handlers on the jQuery api docs ( http://api.jquery.com/trigger ) and they don't seem to be possible in script#.

Comment: Consider using a closure -- it might not be the "best" answer, but it should work. (I can only hope that Script# knows how to generate closures ;-)

Comment: Complain that `Script#` should implement this feature. You could try to monkey patch `trigger` and `bind` but god knows how you would do that in `Script#`

Comment: Also a sneaky recommendation that plain JavaScript development is preferable if you have the chance to learn js and are not hit with deadlines.

Comment: Many people learning Script# already have a worthwhile reason in mind for doing so.

Comment: @DuckMaestro that reason being "I'm an expert .NET developer. I don't have time to learn JavaScript because we have strict deadlines"

Comment: @Raynos. Beats me. I consider myself an expert in JavaScript, but I still find compelling reasons to use Script# for a number of applications. Alot depends on what you're looking to build. I wouldn't outright discourage someone from using Script# unless you qualify it with the pros/cons and what projects are appropriate.

Comment: @DuckMaestro what are the compelling reason to learn Script# if your a js expert? (Might want to take that to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript))

Comment: Typos are caught at compile-time instead of run-time. Strong-typing adds a basic level of code contracts. The ability to use Visual Studio refactoring/analysis tools. Code reuse between client-side and server-side C#. Code reuse between client-side web apps and client-side WPF/WinForms/Silverlight apps. Stronger intellisense.

Comment: @Raynos - script# is first-and-foremost about a better set of end-to-end tools for effectively developing/managing a large project (eg. large codebase, bigger team, long-lived app etc.) rather than a way to hide/abstract or stay away from javascript.

Comment: @NikhilK I'm on the other side of the fence on that one. We should build tools for developing large JavaScript projects. Not use tools for other languages and compile down to C#. Script# would be better if it was completely open source ;) @DuckMaestro I have to agree that visual studio has some nice refactoring/analysis tools (WebStorms is catching up though).

Comment: @Raynos - the plan is certainly to make it all open source. Its on its way. As for better tools for script - no question about that being worthwhile, but re-implementing the rich and varied .net tools ecosystem is likely going to take some while as well. Many of those existing tools become effective and relevant today... besides the pattern of compiling to script is not new. Source != runtime script - they are optimized for different needs (whether you use java to script with gwt, or annotated script to script with closure as couple more examples of this approach)

Comment: @NikhilK I have no objection to compiling down to js. It's a mess. I would prefer a toolset build around CoffeeScript though. C# and Java just don't really match with JavaScript. and Closure has a different purpose (optimising the hell out of your javascript). I also don't think we should re-implement the .net tools ecosystem. We should make tools for js from the ground up that are suited for the tasks. Oh and awesome news about it going OS o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to DuckMaestro's suggestion -

The sources for Script.jQuery are on github ... they're there so people can change it, not be blocked, and not have to resort to things like InvokeMethod, Script.Literal and other such sub-optimal workarounds.

The reason the signature is not like that to begin with is every event handler shouldn't need to define extra parameters in its signature when not needed.

**Option 1** -

Create a different delegate signature - like jQueryEventHandler. And then create overloads of Bind, and Trigger that use your new signature. Its not hard, esp. if you look at the existing implementation source as a reference.

**Option 2** -

Use the other pattern suggested by examples at http://api.jquery.com/trigger.

```
var event = jQuery.Event("item-added");
event.item = "ball";
$("#someid").trigger(event);
```

Specifically add properties to jQueryEvent and then create the derived class where you trigger the event, set properties on it for your specific scenarios. And then in the event handler cast the jQueryEvent back to the specific type.

The nice thing about this is it is consistent with the DOM... in terms of what you'd do with document.createEvent, and dispatchEvent. As such I prefer this option, besides the fact that it doesn't need overloads of bind/trigger for every specific scenario.

The one thing you'll run into right now is jQueryEvent itself is sealed right now, but I am happy to make that unsealed to support these scenarios (be sure to log a bug on github so it can be tracked). In the mean-time to be unblocked, you have the sources to make it unsealed on your end.

If you really don't want to get into rebuilding Script.jQuery, a temporary workaround (until you have a build where you can start deriving from) is the following:

```
jQueryEvent e = jQuery.Event("item-added");
Script.Literal("{0}.item = {1}", e, "ball");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options but the path of least resistance is probably to do the following:

```
void OnItemAdded(jQueryEvent e, Object[] args) { /* your handler */ }

// ...

    jQueryObject myElement = jQuery.Select("#someId");
    Type.InvokeMethod(myElement, "bind", "item-added", new Action<jQueryEvent, Object[]>(OnItemAdded));

// ...
```

Another option would be to subclass `jQueryObject`, add a new delegate type, and a new signature for `Bind` that takes your delegate.

By the way, unless you need to pass an array of arguments, you can leave off the array syntax all throughout, using `Object` instead of `Object[]`; or better yet, use just `string` if you know your incoming argument can strictly be a string.